# Setting PSDscAllowPlaintextPassword as true from terraform

Tags: powershell, terraform

I'm using terraform and powershell DSC to set up an active directory domain controller.

Everything works when I run the script in the server because I can specify a configuration data with "PSDscAllowPlaintextPassword" set to true (I know is not the best practice but is what we need now).

However when running this script from a terraform extension, what happens is that no configuration data is provided and I'm not able (or I don't know how) to set that as true to have the script working.

I would like to either be able to specify PSDscAllowPlaintextPassword as true inside the node definition (with no need for a configurationdata) or be able to send it from the terraform extension.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

So we finally discovered how to do it.

We call the powershell script from terraform with something like this:

```
  resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  count                      = "1"
  name                       = "xxx"
  location                   = "xxx"
  resource_group_name        = "xxx"
  virtual_machine_name       = "xxx"
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Powershell"
  type                       = "DSC"
  type_handler_version       = "2.73"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "configuration": {
        "url": "package_url",
        "script": "scriptforactivedomain.ps1",
        "function": "functionname"
      }
    }
SETTINGS

  tags {
    environment = "xxx"
    category    = "xxx"
  }
}
```

We just need to add a snippet to the settings area:

```
  settings = <<SETTINGS
{
  "configuration": {
    "url": "package_url",
    "script": "scriptforactivedomain.ps1",
    "function": "functionname"
  },
   "configurationData": {
    "url": "url_to_file_with_configuration_data.psd1"
  }
}
```

SETTINGS

Then in the .psd1 we just specify the config data as we normally would do:

```
@{
   AllNodes = @(
       @{
            NodeName = 'localhost'
            PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
            }
        )
    }
```

In this case was pretty simple but I was busting my head off!